# SQL FOR EACH?

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns, userID and contentID. Basically this table is used to assign access to certain content to specific users. I have the request of every user that is assigned to content A also be assigned to content B. So how would I write a new row with this data (userid, [id of content B]) for each row that has (userid, [id of content A])?

OK I tried what the top two posts said and it converted it to:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_courseAccess
                      (contentid)
SELECT     11 AS Expr1
WHERE     (contentid = 6)
```

and didn't work, so I'm not sure what I did wrong, here is what I tried to use:

```
insert into tbl_contentAccess
(userid, contentid)
select userid, 11
where contentid = 6
```

OK I found a new solution, don't worry about this anymore, thanks everyone.

Comment: Ryan, can you give us a better detailed table structure?  From my understanding as well as many others, you can do this with a smart insert statement but we need more info.

Comment: it's like two columns, userid, contentid, so each row is like: 0, 5 or 12, 6 etc. I just need every row that is userid, 6 to cause a new row userid, 11 for each one, they are both marked as primary keys

Comment: You forgot the from in your select. or the answerers did. Add it and it should work.

Comment: yeah I tried adding the from and still got some primary key constraint error, could it be because some users are already assigned to both 6 and 11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into <table>(userid, contentid)
select userid, [content b id] from <table> where contentid = [content a id]))
```

**Corrected:** Typing too fast to race you other answerers

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into [tablename]
(userid, contentid)
select userid, [id of content B]
where contentid = [id of content A]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    insert into your_table(userid, contentid) select userid, 
[id of content B] from your_table where contentid = [id of content A])
```

That should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (userID,contentID) 
  SELECT userID,[id of content B] FROM mytable 
    WHERE content = [id of content A];
```